# How open new window with base64 PDF content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

I want open new window (with jQuery) and show PDF from base64 content. When I make normal link:

```
<a href=\"data:application/pdf;base64,'.$answer->shipping_label_content.'\" target=\"blank\">Show PDF</a>
```

It's all good. But I want automatic open new window with this content and I don't know how :-/

```
var window = window.open();
var html = "data:application/pdf;base64,'.$answer->shipping_label_content.'";

$(window.document.body).html(html);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can generate a temp `anchor` and click programmatically.

```
//this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,'.$answer->shipping_label_content.'";

//Set properties as you wise
link.download = "SomeName";
link.target = "blank";

//this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Comment: This work, like 
     window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,'.$answer->shipping_label_content.'", "_blank", '');

but Safari blocked first and second :-/

Comment: This solution does not work for IE.Any alternative solution to make this work in IE?

Comment: @Siddharth_Vyas, You can look at [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)