# how to display a pdf attachment on the browser with gmailApi using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

how to implement the callback function for a pdf document to show it in the browser by clicking on a link

```
 /**
     * Get Attachments from a given Message.
     *
     * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
     * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
     * @param  {String} messageId ID of Message with attachments.
     * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
     */
    function getAttachments(userId, message, callback) {
      var parts = message.payload.parts;
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var part = parts[i];
        if (part.filename && part.filename.length > 0) {
          var attachId = part.body.attachmentId;
          var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
            'id': attachId,
            'messageId': message.id,
            'userId': userId
          });
          request.execute(function(attachment) {
            callback(part.filename, part.mimeType, attachment);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: [This trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341216/how-open-new-window-with-base64-pdf-content) seems to work in every browser.